# nodejs+puppeteer in docker: Unexpected Identifier on import statement

Tags: node.js, docker, puppeteer

I'm trying to run an application that requires puppeteer in a docker container and I get the following error when I run the docker container

```sh
/usr/src/app/index.js:1
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
       ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y imagemagick ghostscript nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y npm
RUN npm ci
CMD ["node","index.js"]
```

I'm developing this app on a windows machine and the app runs fine on windows but for some reason when either A) Running the app on an ubuntu vm or B) Running the app in a docker container I get this error

Comment: Check your package-lock.json. Looks like you install puppeteer globally on your windows machine.

Comment: Puppeteer does seem to exist in my package-lock.json. `npm i puppeteer` only seems to change the installed version form 13.1.2 to 13.1.3

Comment: @BrandonPina try using " npm update", it should update the package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem ended up being that installing nodejs through apt-get installs nodejs 10.something.something. I'm using es6 syntax which wasn't stable until 12ish so I had to modify my dockerfile to install the correct version of nodejs

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `puppeteer` is part of your dependencies in your `package.json`,

then try the following instead in your script `/usr/src/app/index.js`:

```
import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";
```

as I don't think the `puppeteer` package has a `puppeteer` export.

The fact that it works on windows with `import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';` is a mystery though...